# Get the number of connections to the Active Directory in a date range and grouped by user

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to retrieve the number of connections done to Active Directory between two dates. I would like to group the result by user. Is that possible? If so, how?

I know logs are stored in Windows Event Viewer. I have found [this script](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51413.active-directory-how-to-get-user-login-history-using-powershell.aspx) in PowerShell to retrieve logs from Windows Event Viewer with event ID "4624: An account was successfully logged on" but it seems it does not work. It is not displaying any result. Logs in event viewer with event ID 4624 are found for some DC domains, but they are not being displayed as output.

I have modified that script as below to indicate date range:

```
# Get your ad domain
$DomainName = (Get-ADDomain).DNSRoot
Write-Host $DomainName

# Find DC list from Active Directory
$DCs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter * -Server $DomainName

# Define time for report
$Begin = Get-Date -Date '01/09/2019 00:00:00' # mm/dd/yyyy
$End = Get-Date -Date '10/09/2019 23:59:59'   # mm/dd/yyyy

# Store successful logon events from security logs with the specified
# dates and workstation/IP in an array
foreach ($DC in $DCs) {
    Write-Host "HOST NAME: " $DC.Hostname
    # 4624: An account was successfully logged on
    $slogonevents = Get-Eventlog -LogName Security -ComputerName $DC.Hostname -After $Begin -Before $End |
                    where {$_.eventID -eq 4624 }

    Write-Host $slogonevents.Count

    # Crawl through events; print all logon history with type, date/time,
    # status, account name, computer and IP address if user logged on remotely
    foreach ($e in $slogonevents) {
        # Logon Successful Events
        # Local (Logon Type 2)
        if (($e.EventID -eq 4624 ) -and ($e.ReplacementStrings[8] -eq 2)){
            Write-Host "Type: Local Logon`tDate: "$e.TimeGenerated "`tStatus: Success`tUser: "$e.ReplacementStrings[5] "`tWorkstation: "$e.ReplacementStrings[11]
        }

        # Remote (Logon Type 10)
        if (($e.EventID -eq 4624 ) -and ($e.ReplacementStrings[8] -eq 10)){
            Write-Host "Type: Remote Logon`tDate: "$e.TimeGenerated "`tStatus: Success`tUser: "$e.ReplacementStrings[5] "`tWorkstation: "$e.ReplacementStrings[11] "`tIP Address: "$e.ReplacementStrings[18]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could be an issue with log size? How many events do you have in the security logs? We have hundreds of thousands and we'd probably run into PS memory issues trying to run this script

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify: You're saying that some events are found but are not being displayed as output:
They are found in the event logs but not by the script OR they are found by the script but not being output by the script?

Test this line against a DC with known 4624 entries:

```
$slogonevents = Get-Eventlog -LogName Security -ComputerName $DC.Hostname -After $Begin -Before $End | where {$_.eventID -eq 4624 }
```

If entries are not found check again that entries exist in the event log and that you're not mixing up date formats - maybe your dev PC is using a different datetime format than your server? (mm/dd/yyyy vs dd/mm/yyyy often causes issues)

If entries are found by the script verify why your if statement is filtering them out:

```
if (($e.EventID -eq 4624 ) -and ($e.ReplacementStrings[8] -eq 2))
```